# Is there a way to tell Drupal not to cache a specific page?

Tags: php, drupal, rss, picasa

I have a custom php page that processes a feed of images and makes albums out of it. However whenever i add pictures to my feed, the Drupal page doesn't change until I clear the caches.

Is there a way to tell Drupal not to cache that specific page?

Thanks,
Blake

Edit: Drupal v6.15
Not exactly sure what you mean oswald, team2648.com/media is hte page.
I used the php interpreter module. Here is the php code:

```
    <?php
//////// CODE by Pikori Web Designs - pikori.org   ///////////
//////// Please do not remove this title,          ///////////
//////// feel free to modify or copy this software ///////////
$feedURL = 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/Techplex.Engineer?alt=rss&kind=album&hl=en_US';


$photoNodeNum = 4;
$galleryTitle = 'Breakaway Pictures';
$year = '2011';
?>



<?php
  /////////////// DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE //////////////////

$album = $_GET['album'];
if($album != ""){

  //GENERATE PICTURES
  $feedURL= "http://".$album."&kind=photo&hl=en_US";
  $feedURL = str_replace("entry","feed",$feedURL);

  $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
  $column = 0;
  $pix_count = count($sxml->channel->item);

  //print '<h2>'.$sxml->channel->title.'</h2>';
  print '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:10pt" width="100%"><tr>';
  for($i = 0; $i < $pix_count; $i++) { 

print '<td align="center">';
$entry = $sxml->channel->item[$i];
$picture_url = $entry->enclosure['url'];
$time = $entry->pubDate;
$time_ln = strlen($time)-14;
$time = substr($time,0,$time_ln);
$description = $entry->description;
$tn_beg = strpos($description, "src=");
$tn_end = strpos($description, "alt=");
$tn_length = $tn_end - $tn_beg;
$tn = substr($description, $tn_beg, $tn_length);
$tn_small = str_replace("s288","s128",$tn);

$picture_url = $tn;
$picture_beg = strpos($picture_url,"http:");
$picture_len = strlen($picture_url)-7;
$picture_url = substr($tn, $picture_beg, $picture_len);
$picture_url = str_replace("s288","s640",$picture_url);
print '<a rel="lightbox[group]" href="'.$picture_url.'">';
print '<img '.$tn_small.' style="border:1px solid #02293a"><br>';
print '</a></td> ';

if($column == 4){ print '</tr><tr>'; $column = 0;}
else $column++;
  }
  print '</table>';
  print '<br><center><a href="media">Return to album</a></center>';
} else {

  //GENERATE ALBUMS 
  $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
  $column = 0;
  $album_count = count($sxml->channel->item);

  //print '<h2>'.$galleryTitle.'</h2>';
  print '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:10pt" width="100%"><tr>';
  for($i = 0; $i < $album_count; $i++) { 

$entry = $sxml->channel->item[$i];

$time = $entry->pubDate;
$time_ln = strlen($time)-14;
$time = substr($time,0,$time_ln);

$description = $entry->description;
$tn_beg = strpos($description, "src=");
$tn_end = strpos($description, "alt=");
$tn_length = $tn_end - $tn_beg;
$tn = substr($description, $tn_beg, $tn_length);

$albumrss = $entry->guid;
$albumrsscount = strlen($albumrss) - 7;
$albumrss = substr($albumrss, 7, $albumrsscount);

$search = strstr($time, $year);
if($search != FALSE || $year == ''){
  print '<td valign="top">';
  print '<a href="/node/'.$photoNodeNum.'?album='.$albumrss.'">';
  print '<center><img '.$tn.' style="border:3px double #cccccc"><br>';
  print $entry->title.'<br>'.$time.'</center>';
  print '</a><br></td> ';

  if($column == 3){ 
    print '</tr><tr>'; $column = 0;
  } else {
    $column++;
  }
} 
  }
  print '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please specify the version of Drupal you use. Caching changed in Drupal 7. Also, how did you implement the page?

Comment: For Drupal8, this can be done programmatically, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151254/how-can-i-prevent-a-particular-page-being-cached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.

The site you linked gave me some new verbiage to search with, and thus I found this:
http://www.drupalcoder.com/story/365-disable-drupals-page-cache-for-some-pages

which then led me to this:
http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude

which did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[Hope this helps.](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-not-cache-a-particular-drupal-page)

That is for Drupal 6.

Comment: So it's not some snippet of code i can place at the bottom of the page? That looks like I have to make my own module. Also it would be nice to be able to use this on multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your specific question about caching, but -- consider using Drupal-native solutions like the [Picasa](http://drupal.org/project/picasa) module for things like this.

When you use non-Drupal PHP applications in a Drupal environment like you have here, you get weird interactions with other Drupal components. Drupal modules are build with Drupal in mind, so things like sane caching usually come built in.

Comment: It would be nice to have a module to do what I want, However I am unable to get the Picasa module to function. Google tells me that it received a malformed request.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code line at the top of the custom page you dont want to be cached:

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6,

If you just want to exclude a specific page from being cached then you can use Cache exclude module, where you just have to provide a url.

for drupal 7 also it is available but its in the development version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it programmatically and the below code is valid for Drupal 6 and 7 both.

Reference : http://techrappers.com/post/27/how-prevent-javascript-and-css-render-some-drupal-pages

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_init() {
global $conf;
// current_path() is the path on which you want to turn of JS or CSS cache
  if (current_path() == 'batch' || current_path() == 'library-admin') {
    // If you want to force CSS or JS cache to turned off
    $conf['preprocess_js'] = FALSE;
    $conf['preprocess_css'] = FALSE;

    // If you want normal caching to turned off 
     drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE); 
  } 
}
```

Please Note that  drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE); can only turn off normal caching, it will not force JS caching to be turned off automatically unless you use $conf['preprocess_js'] = FALSE.